# undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, dijkstra

I am a beginner in ruby Here I am attaching my errorful code please help me to resolve the error in my Dijkstra algorithm implementation in Ruby

```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby

def minDistance(dist,sptSet)
 min=999,min_index=0,v=0
 for v in 0...9 
 if sptSet[v]==false && dist[v]<=999
   min=dist[v],min_index=v
 end
 end
return min_index
end

   def printSolution(dist,n)
    puts "Vertex  Distance from Source"
    for i in 0...9
    puts "#{i}  #{dist[i]}"
    end
     end

    def dijkstra(graph,src)
    dist=Array.new(9)
    sptSet=Array.new(9)

    for i in 0...9
     dist[i]=999,sptSet=false
     end
     dist[src]=0
     for count in 0...8
     u=minDistance(dist,sptSet)
     sptSet[u]=true
     for v in 0...9
     if sptSet[v]==false && graph[u][v] && dist[u]!=999 && dist[u]+graph[u] [v]<dist[v]
    dist[v]=dist[u]+graph[u][v]
    end
    end
    end
     printSolution(dist,9)
     end


   def main

     graph=[[0,4,0,0,0,0,0,8,0],[4,0,8,0,0,0,0,11,0],[0,8,0,7,0,4,0,0,2],[0,0,7,0,9,14,0,0,0],[0,0,0,9,0,10,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,14,0,2,0,1,6],[8,11,0,0,0,0,1,0,7],[0,0,2,0,0,0,6,7,0]]


    dijkstra(graph,0)

      end

      main
```

Below is the error that is shown to me. Please help me to find where i am doing the mistake with a proper explaination

```
            in `block in minDistance': undefined method `[]' for     false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
            from rubyfirst.rb:5:in `each'
            from rubyfirst.rb:5:in `minDistance'
            from rubyfirst.rb:29:in `block in dijkstra'
           from rubyfirst.rb:28:in `each'
           from rubyfirst.rb:28:in `dijkstra'
           from rubyfirst.rb:46:in `main'
           from rubyfirst.rb:50:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Dont use CamelCase in variables or methods. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is rather hard to understand but intuition tells me the problem is with line 
`dist[i]=999,sptSet=false`

because 3 lines before you are defining sptSet with
`sptSet=Array.new(9)`

so at first you are making array, and then you are changing it to false. probably what you wanted to achieve is:
`dist[i]=999,sptSet[i]=false`

Comment: thanks...after correcting it i m getting another error:  `block in minDistance': undefined method `<=' for [999, false]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: change `dist[i]=999,sptSet=false` to 

dist[i]=999


sptSet=false

` (so remove `,` and add enter after 999)

Comment: thanks  the error got resolved but another error occurred instead: rubyfirst.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in dijkstra': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: probably because your graph array consists only of 8 subarrays (I guess it should be 9)

Comment: after doing all the corrections i m getting this out put:0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
6  0
7  0
8  0

Answer (score 1):

You assign `false` to `sptSet`

```
 dist[i]=999,sptSet=false
```

pass it to `minDistance`,and than in this methods body you expect sptSet to be an `Array`

```
if sptSet[v]==false && dist[v]<=999
```

Answer (score 0):

My Dijkstra implementation example:

```
class Dijkstra
    attr_accessor :graph, :origin, :destination, :edges, :verticies

    def initialize(origin, destination, edges)
        self.graph = []
        self.edges = edges
        self.verticies = unique_verticies
        populate_graph(origin, destination)
    end

    def populate_graph(origin, destination)
        self.origin = origin
        self.destination = destination
        self.graph = create_nodes
        populate_neighbors
        recursive_dijkstra
    end

    def shortest_distance
        self.graph.detect { |node| node[:vertex] == self.destination }[:distance]
    end

    def shortest_path
        path = [self.destination]
        predecessor = self.destination
        while !predecessor.nil?
            predecessor = self.graph.detect { |node| node[:vertex] == predecessor }[:predecessor]
            path.unshift(predecessor) unless predecessor.nil?
        end
        path
    end

    private

    def unique_verticies
        self.edges.flatten.uniq.select { |edge| edge.class == String }
    end

    def create_nodes
        self.verticies.map do |vertex|
            node = { vertex: vertex, closed: false, predecessor: nil, distance: Float::INFINITY, neighbors: [] }
            node[:distance] = 0 if vertex == origin
            node
        end
    end

    def populate_neighbors
      self.verticies.each do |vertex|
        self.edges.each do |edge|
          if edge.include?(vertex)
            self.graph.detect { |node| node[:vertex] == vertex }[:neighbors] << edge.detect { |neighbor| neighbor != vertex && neighbor.class == String }
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def recursive_dijkstra
        open_verticies = self.graph.select { |node| node[:closed] == false }.sort_by { |node| node[:distance] }
        return if open_verticies.count == 0
        node = open_verticies.first
        node[:closed] = true
        node[:neighbors].each do |neighbor|
            neighbor_vertex = self.graph.detect { |node| node[:vertex] == neighbor && node[:closed] == false }
            next if neighbor_vertex.nil?
            self.edges.each do |edge|
                if edge.include?(node[:vertex]) && edge.include?(neighbor_vertex[:vertex])
                    matcher_distance = node[:distance] + edge[2]
                    if matcher_distance < neighbor_vertex[:distance]
                        neighbor_vertex[:distance] = matcher_distance
                        neighbor_vertex[:predecessor] = node[:vertex]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        recursive_dijkstra
    end
end
```

you have to pass the edges in the format

```
[['vertex_1', 'vertex_2', weight], ['vertex_2', 'vertex_3', weight ], ...]
```